# @Html.ActionLink changes URL but doesn't redirect to destination In asp.net MVC-5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

I have read and implemented almost all solutions. but it doesnt seem to be working enough for me.

When I run my application (in localhost)

1). Login Page comes,

```
 http://localhost/  (called login.cshtml)

 Controller: LoginCotroller
 action    : Login
```

2). For authenticated users it  redirects to user locations page

```
http://localhost/Locations/UserLocations (called locations.cshtml)

Controller: Locations
actions   : UserLocations
```

Now complex part comes,

after selecting particular location, user redirects to Dashboard.cshtml. 
and at a same time angularjs comes into picture. 
Dashboard.cshtml header has two links

```
1.Change Locations  //@Html.ActionLink

2.SignOut           //@Html.ActionLink
```

3) shows Dashboard

```
http://localhost/Home/Dashboard

Controller: Home
action    : Dashboard
```

Till here everything works just fine.

But problem is above two links don't work properly. When I click link it changes Url but doesn't redirect me to particular action method.

```
Note: when url is changed, I have to go to browser's address bar and 

explicitly hit enter to redirect myself to destination( I don't want that)
```

I have tried almost all possible ways but still not working for me.

What i have done is,

for change location link,

```
1)@Html.ActionLink("Change Location", "UserLocations", "Locations");
2)@Html.ActionLink("Change Location", "UserLocations", "Locations",null,null);
3)@Html.ActionLink("Change Location", "UserLocations", "Locations",new{},new{});
```

for SignOut link,

```
1)@Html.ActionLink("SignOut", "Logout", "Login");
2)@Html.ActionLink("SignOut", "Logout", "Login",null,null);
3)@Html.ActionLink("SignOut", "Logout", "Login",new{},{});
```

I have following Routing for MVC

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Customers", "{customer}/Login", new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }, null);

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "",
            url: "{angularRoute}",
            defaults: new 
            { 
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Dashboard", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new 
            { 
                controller = "Login", 
                action = "Login", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: While working with routes, the order we specify them does matter a lot.
It seems your first route 
[ routes.MapRoute("Customers", "{customer}/Login", new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }, null);] 
is mapped incorrect try to remove it , and specify your generic route first which mapped is in last :
[ routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new 
            { 
                controller = "Login", 
                action = "Login", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply stop Angular from processing the link and instead use the MVC route, add a target to self:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "Home", null, new { target = "_self" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all these three:

```js
1)@Html.ActionLink("Change Location", "UserLocations", "Locations");
2)@Html.ActionLink("Change Location", "UserLocations", "Locations",null,null);
3)@Html.ActionLink("Change Location", "UserLocations", "Locations",new{},new{});
```

Try something simpler for defining ActionLinks.

```js
@Html.ActionLink("Change Location", "UserLocations", new { controller = "Locations" });
```

**EDIT:**

```js
routes.MapRoute("Customers", "{customer}/Login", new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }, null);
```

What do you exactly want to achieve with this route?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. please check this question of mine. I feel like you can definitely help me out...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008687/default-dynamic-static-route-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: I will check it and will write an advice if I know any solution for it. Does my answer solved what you were trying to achieve here? What's the thing with the route I have wrote on the edit?

Comment: Also, if my solution solved your problem, mark it as an answer so anyone else that faces similar problem can see how to solve it. But, if that didn't helped, but a comment down so I can help you further.

Comment: Its not working. I've found a reason. Its because angularjs. But i still don't know how to overcome. else its working in anyway. It gets conflicted with angularjs routing.

Comment: I can not help you with that, as I have never working before with `angular.js`. Also, I made a post in the other thread you have created, check it. If I can help you further here, notify me.